# Xamarin - Customizing iPhoneSimulator list in VS2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have VS2017 (Windows) version 15.9.4 paired to Mac XCode 10.1. VS2017 is listing combination of iPhoneSimulators in its small dropdown list (see screenshot). Sometimes I could not find the simulator I need as it is buried in a long list. Is there a way or workaround to customize this dropdown list without adjusting XCode device configuration?

[image: iPhoneSimulator list]

Comment: None that I am aware of if you ask me, One thing you could do is change the target and that would make the list a little smaller but i don't think that is what you need here